# KIVY: Button background not displayed despite source being specified

Tags: python, image, button, background, kivy

I am having a strange issue in Kivy where a button's `background_normal` and `background_down` values are being set to a directory path which is `'images/icons/software_icon.jpg'` however when my program is started, the image is not displayed and I am given the basic grey box that Kivy buttons default to. My guess is that Kivy is not finding the image in the directory I've given it however I have ensured that the image is in the correct directory. This method has worked with all my other buttons in my code so I'm not sure what's going on. Here is my code:

```
    Button:

        id: power_button

        text: ''
        background_normal: 'images/icons/power_icon.jpg'
        background_down: 'images/icons/power_icon.jpg'
        center_x: 1520
        center_y: 120
        texture: self.texture
        height: 50
        width: 50
        opacity: 0
        disabled: True
        on_press:
            root.powerOff()
    Button:

        id: settings_button

        text: ''
        background_normal: 'images/icons/settings_icon.jpg'
        background_down: 'images/icons/settings_icon.jpg'
        center_x: 1520
        center_y: 190
        texture: self.texture
        height: 50
        width: 50
        opacity: 0 
        disabled: True
        on_press:
            pass 

    Button:

        id: os_button

        text: ''
        background_normal: 'images/icons/software_icon.jpg'
        background_down: 'images/icons/software_icon.jpg'
        center_x: 1520
        center_y: 260
        texture: self.texture
        height: 50
        width: 50
        opacity: 0
        disabled: True 
        on_press:
            pass
```

The output:
[image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc48h.png)

Any ideas as to what I should do now?

Comment: `opacity: 0` will make the `Button` invidible.

Comment: The opacity isn't the issue as in my ```.py``` file I have a function that sets the button's opacities to 100 when the 'menu' button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution!** I'm still unclear as to why this made any difference but I am not complaining. Anyways here is the newly updated code for the button in the `.kv` file:

```
    Button:

        id: os_button

        text: ''
        center_x: 1910
        center_y: 260
        texture: self.texture
        height: 50
        width: 50
        opacity: 0
        disabled: True 
        on_press:
            pass

        Image:
            source: 'images/icons/soft_icon.jpg'
            size: os_button.size
            pos: os_button.pos
```

So just adding the `Image` attribute instead of the `background_normal` and `background_down` attributes cleared up the issue. Hopefully this helps anyone having the same issue in the future!

New result: [FINAL RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nRSH.png)